# different result from file reading and standard input with getline

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, boost

```
bool validateCurrencyLine(string line){
    cout << "TESTING LINE : " << line << endl;
    string pattern = "[ ]*([A-Z]{3}) ([0-9]+)([ ]*|,[0-9]+[ ]*)";
    boost::regex expr{pattern};
    return boost::regex_match(line,expr);
}

int main()
{
    string line;
    while(getline(cin,line)){
        cout << validateCurrencyLine(line) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The content of `test` file is as follows:

> IDK 3453443

Now when I start a program using `./a.out < test` the result is

```
TESTING LINE : IDK 3453443
0
TESTING LINE : 
0
```

My assumption is that the second line is printed because the testfile first line is  actually

> IDK 3453443 + enter

Am I correct?)

But the real problem is that when I start it like this: `./a.out` and input "IDK 3453443" and press enter. The result of this is:

```
TESTING LINE : IDK 3453443
1
```

Any thoughts why these two results differ?

Comment: Are you sure you do not have `\r` before `\n` in the file? That can be the culprit... Try `string pattern = "[ ]*([A-Z]{3}) ([0-9]+)([ ]*|,[0-9]+\\s*)";`. Or `regex_search` instead of `regex_match`.

Comment: Unfortunately the new pattern still doesnt work @stribizhev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the line ends are the culprit.

Look at the file in a hex editor, you will find `0d 0a` line ends (Windows or CRLF), where the code expects UNIX line-ends (just LF).

See it live:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07e123460931052d)</kbd>**

You can work around it by 'eating' all whitespace at the end:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0671c28123c7139)</kbd>**

```
std::string pattern = "[ ]*([A-Z]{3}) ([0-9]+)(,[0-9]+)?\\s*";
```

Now both get accepted.